# Fortify Open redirect issue on Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, fortify

```
var param=document.getElementById("test").value;
var url= "http://localhost/app/default.aspx?test="+param;
Window.showModalDialog(url);
```

showModalDialog method line is showing me fortify open redirect issue. Is there anyway I can resolve the issue on client side (in javascript file)?

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify is saying that you're redirecting the user to a new site whose URL is composed of the user's input, which could allow an attacker to phish or perform other attacks if it was manipulated in a special way using the input value. [OWASP.org reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet#Preventing_Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards)

The best way to fix this is to create a white list on the server of acceptable parameters values for the parameter `test`, so when the server receives a request with a value for `test`, it can redirect the user to a page if the value of the parameter is not recognized/invalid. There's no reliable fix for this issue that lies solely on the client side, given the information provided in the question. A regex would help in theory, although I am unsure if Fortify will be happy with a regex sanitation.